# How to perform adjustment with just one loop in golang?

Tags: loops, go

So lets examine there is an array

```golang
arr := []string{"kek", "kok", "hehehe"}
```

So when printing them i want a formatted output like

```
kek      value
kok      value
hehehe   value
```

In this output everything is ordered between the word and `value`.

```golang
maxLength := 0
arr := []string{"kek", "kok", "hehehe"}

for _, name := range arr {
    l := len(name)
    if l > maxLength { maxLength = l }
}

for _, name := range arr {
    fmt.Println(name, strings.Repeat("", (maxLength-len(name))+3), "value")
}
```

I am using this code to generate the output above. This method uses 2 loops. Can i make it 1 loop. And using this code is even worthful? Just a curious question. Thanks.

Comment: You can just guess a suitably large `maxLength` value initially.  Also it should be `strings.Repeat(" ", ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `fmt.Printf` along with the a guessed padding to do it. However if you need to be exact then you'd need the second loop.

```golang
for _, name := range arr {
    fmt.Printf("%-10s\t%s\n", name, "value")
}
```